# Css trick expanding parent div height on overflow

Tags: html, css

How to expand parent div's height (with background) to wrap the child when the child is overflowing ? I may have more than one item with the `class detail`.
When the `div get_there_text` is overflowing its parent, I want the `div detail` to expand its height so the background color will also cover the overflowing content as shown in the example.

You may see the example on fiddle provided below.

```css
#main_content #result{width: 100%;margin-top: 153px}
#main_content .detail{background: #afaafa;width: 758px;margin: 0px auto 20px auto}
#main_content .detail .title{padding-left: 21px;font-size: 28px;font-weight: 700px;padding-top: 19px;border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3}
#main_content .detail .title a{text-decoration: none;color:#F05634}
#main_content .detail .subtitle{font-size: 19px;font-weight: 500px;line-height: 13px;margin-bottom: 15px;}
#main_content .subcontent{width: calc(100% - 40px);margin: 20px;width: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);padding-bottom: 15px}
#main_content .detail .left-col{margin-right: 40px;background-size: cover;height:203px;background-repeat: no-repeat;display: inline-block;width: 40%}
#main_content .detail .right-col{height: auto;position: relative;display: inline-block;width: 53%;font-size: 13px;color: #333333;height: 203px;vertical-align: top}
#main_content .detail .record {line-height: 26px}
#main_content .detail .record .col1{display:inline-block;display: table-cell;width: 113px}
#main_content .detail .record .col2{display:inline-block;display: table-cell;}
#main_content .detail .button-wrapper{position: absolute;bottom: 0}
#main_content .btn-default{width: 200px; height: 41px;color:#FFF;font-size: 19px;font-weight: bold}
#main_content .btn-orange{background-color:#F05634;border:1px solid #F05634}
#main_content .btn-orange.active,#main_content .btn-orange:active,#main_content .btn-orange.focus,#main_content .btn-orange:focus,#main_content .btn-orange:hover{background-color:#F05634;color:#FFF;border:1px solid #F05634;box-shadow:none}
#main_content .btn-inactive{background-color:#999999;cursor:default;}
#main_content .detail .mint-wrapper{position: absolute;bottom: 0;display: inline-block;}
#main_content .detail .mint{cursor: pointer;font-size: 16px;font-weight: 500;width: 262px;height: 32px;background-color: #6CC9C9;color: #ffffff;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;line-height: 32px}
#main_content .detail .get_there_text{display: inline-block;margin-top: 22px;font-size: 13px;font-weight: 500;color: #333333;line-height: 16px;position: absolute;}
#main_content .detail .mint img{margin-left: 7px}
```

```html
<div id="main_content">
  <div id="result">
        <div class="detail">
            <input type="hidden" id="tour_idx" value="<?=$tour->tour_idx?>" />
            <div class="title"><a href="/experience/detail/<?=$tour->custom_url?>" target="_blank">title<br/><span class="subtitle">substitle</span></a></div>
            <div class="subcontent">
              <div class="left-col" background-image="http://curiositysip.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Tulip-8.jpg"></div>
              <div class="right-col">
                  <div class="record">
                    <div class="col1"><b>Meet Location</b></div><div class="col2">meet here</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="record">
                    <div class="col1"><b>Date</b></div><div class="col2">1</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="record">
                    <div class="col1"><b>Time</b></div><div class="col2">2</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="record">
                    <div class="col1"><b>Participants</b></div><div class="col2">1</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mint-wrapper"><div class="mint">How to get there<div class="get_there_text">We are going to meet at around 6PM in front of starbucks, please everyone should wear red shirt on that day and bring a rose with you</div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Expanding div height when child is overflowing](http://jsfiddle.net/paprilia/t6byn73e/1/)

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: As @Paulie_D said, absolute positioning is for special cases (for example a popup), not for layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS @Marcos has told you, you are using an absolute positioned element overflowing the parent. As when you use `position:absolute`you take the elements OUT of html flow it's impossible to make parent height match the children by css.

However if you can't change the `absolute` positioned element, you can always use `jquery`. This script will calculate the height of every element inside your `subcontent` and will apply this height to itself:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".subcontent" ).each(function() {
        var newHeight = 0, $this = $( this );
        $.each( $this.children(), function() {
            newHeight += $( this ).height();
        });
        $this.height( newHeight );
    });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/t6byn73e/3/)**

Comment: Thank you. This really gives me an idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand you, but your problem is the absolute positioning. You must no use absolute positioning without a really deep comprehension of how it works. Here you are the changes:

http://jsfiddle.net/t6byn73e/2/

```
#main_content .detail .get_there_text { position:relative; } 
#main_content .detail .mint-wrapper { position: relative;}
```

See snippet:

```css
#main_content #result{width: 100%;margin-top: 153px}
#main_content .detail{background: #afaafa;width: 758px;margin: 0px auto 20px auto}
#main_content .detail .title{padding-left: 21px;font-size: 28px;font-weight: 700px;padding-top: 19px;border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3}
#main_content .detail .title a{text-decoration: none;color:#F05634}
#main_content .detail .subtitle{font-size: 19px;font-weight: 500px;line-height: 13px;margin-bottom: 15px;}
#main_content .subcontent{width: calc(100% - 40px);margin: 20px;width: -moz-calc(100% - 40px);padding-bottom: 15px}
#main_content .detail .left-col{margin-right: 40px;background-size: cover;height:203px;background-repeat: no-repeat;display: inline-block;width: 40%}
#main_content .detail .right-col{height: auto;position: relative;display: inline-block;width: 53%;font-size: 13px;color: #333333;height: 203px;vertical-align: top}
#main_content .detail .record {line-height: 26px}
#main_content .detail .record .col1{display:inline-block;display: table-cell;width: 113px}
#main_content .detail .record .col2{display:inline-block;display: table-cell;}
#main_content .detail .button-wrapper{position: absolute;bottom: 0}
#main_content .btn-default{width: 200px; height: 41px;color:#FFF;font-size: 19px;font-weight: bold}
#main_content .btn-orange{background-color:#F05634;border:1px solid #F05634}
#main_content .btn-orange.active,#main_content .btn-orange:active,#main_content .btn-orange.focus,#main_content .btn-orange:focus,#main_content .btn-orange:hover{background-color:#F05634;color:#FFF;border:1px solid #F05634;box-shadow:none}
#main_content .btn-inactive{background-color:#999999;cursor:default;}
#main_content .detail .mint-wrapper{position: absolute;bottom: 0;display: inline-block;}
#main_content .detail .mint{cursor: pointer;font-size: 16px;font-weight: 500;width: 262px;height: 32px;background-color: #6CC9C9;color: #ffffff;text-align: center;vertical-align: middle;line-height: 32px}
#main_content .detail .get_there_text{display: inline-block;margin-top: 22px;font-size: 13px;font-weight: 500;color: #333333;line-height: 16px;position: absolute;}
#main_content .detail .mint img{margin-left: 7px}

#main_content .detail .get_there_text { position:relative; } 
#main_content .detail .mint-wrapper { position: relative;}
```

```html
<div id="main_content">
  <div id="result">
        <div class="detail">
            <input type="hidden" id="tour_idx" value="<?=$tour->tour_idx?>" />
            <div class="title"><a href="/experience/detail/<?=$tour->custom_url?>" target="_blank">title<br/><span class="subtitle">substitle</span></a></div>
            <div class="subcontent">
              <div class="left-col" background-image="http://curiositysip.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Tulip-8.jpg"></div>
              <div class="right-col">
                  <div class="record">
                    <div class="col1"><b>Meet Location</b></div><div class="col2">meet here</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="record">
                    <div class="col1"><b>Date</b></div><div class="col2">1</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="record">
                    <div class="col1"><b>Time</b></div><div class="col2">2</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="record">
                    <div class="col1"><b>Participants</b></div><div class="col2">1</div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mint-wrapper"><div class="mint">How to get there<div class="get_there_text">We are going to meet at around 6PM in front of starbucks, please everyone should wear red shirt on that day and bring a rose with you</div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```